# How to change page url on xenforo and apache2?

Tags: apache, xenforo

Does anyone know how I can change http://mywebsite.com/pages/vote to http://mywebsite.com/vote? I'm using apache2 and xenforo.

Comment: You could use `mod_rewrite` to forward the user to the other URL, but your forum needs to provide the page on the new URL

Answer (score 0):

Jake Bruce has a Xenforo addon for this.

See: https://xenforo.com/community/resources/route-changer.447/